# Can anyone explain the concept of median rank?

Tags: probability

http://reliawiki.org/index.php/Parameter_Estimation I found some things here but it does not make me understand it.

For example, if I have data:

```
1 piece 10.91 MR
2 pieces 26.55 MR
3 pieces 42.18 MR
4 pieces 57.32 MR
5 pieces 73.75 MR
6 pieces 89.09 MR
```

How would you interpret it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following three questions have similar answers

**Question 1.** Suppose you have any random variable $Y$ with a continuous cumulative distribution function $F(y)=\mathbb P(Y \le y)$, you sample $6$ observations, order these, and consider the distribution of the $n$th ordered observation counting from the lowest; let's call this $Y_{(n)}$.  The distribution of $Y_{(n)}$ will have a median, say $m_n$.  What is $F(m_n)$?

**Question 2.** Suppose you have a random variable $U$ with a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, you sample $6$ observations, order these, and consider the distribution of the $n$th ordered observation counting from the lowest; let's call this $U_{(n)}$.  The distribution of $U_{(n)}$ will have a median, say $u_n$.  What is $u_n$?

**Question 3.** Suppose you have a random variable $B$ with a [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with parameters $\alpha=n$ and $\beta=7-n$.  The distribution of $B$ will have a median, say $b_n$.  What is $b_n$?

The answer to all three questions is the value $k$ which makes $$\int_{x=0}^k \frac{(n-1)!(6-n)!}{6!} x^{n-1}(1-x)^{6-n}\,dx = \frac12$$

In your question, the suggested interpretation is that of question 1, i.e. how far up the probability distribution is a sample ordered value likely to be centred on, in the sense of being equally likely to be above or below that point in the original distribution, described the *median rank*.

In my view, question 2 gives a simpler way of conceptualising this, while question 3 gives a way of easily calculating the six answers for different $n \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, for example in R:

```
qbeta(1/2 , 1:6, 6:1)
```

giving

```
# [1] 0.1091013 0.2644500 0.4214072 0.5785928 0.7355500 0.8908987
```

and you can see that these are close to the percentages in your question, and even closer to the values in the page you link to.